# How to identify directory level-up matching root in regex?

Tags: php, regex, pcre

I am creating a simple file manager that scans the directory and lists the files and directories in it, including the level-up three dots `../`. my "root" directory is `E:/wamp/www`, and I don't want it to allow me access the parent directory.

I am using the following regular expression:

```
(^E\:\/wamp\/www\/)(\.\.\/$|\.\.\/.*?(\.\.\/)+$)|(^E\:\/wamp\/www\/([^\/]+\/)+)(\.\.\/.*?(\.\.\/)+)
```

in order to prevent the following situations:

1. E:/wamp/www/../
2. E:/wamp/www/dir/../../
3. E:/wamp/www/dir/subdir/../../../

But I've found out that it's also possible to do something such:

- E:/wamp/www/dir/../dir/../../

etc.

How can I prevent such situations and limit it to be only `E:/wamp/www` using regular expressions when it's happening?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `realpath()` function : [realpath](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.realpath.php)

From the documentation :

> realpath() expands all symbolic links and resolves references to /./, /../ and extra / characters in the input path and returns the canonicalized absolute pathname.

Don't rely only on your code to prevent files being written where they should not be written, set proper permissions on your directories.

Comment: It's a good solution but I am afraid it might prevent accessing to parent directories of sub directories because if I understand correct it removes all `../`, also I must use regex for this

Comment: It does not remove the `../`, it resolves them. For example : `realpath('C:\xampp\htdocs\drought\images\..\images\..\..\drought')` gives me `C:\xampp\htdocs\drought`

Comment: but you can still do: `realpath('C:\xampp\htdocs\drought\images\..\images\..\..\drought\..\..\')` and such things no?

Comment: @user11247237 You can use the output of this function and validate it.